# Word Insert Cell without add a new Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

suppose I have 4X4 table in MS Word 
[image]

Now I want to add new cell before 3 and wants to shift remain cell data to next cell maintaining table structure (like text wrap)

Like This -

[image]

But I am getting this result -

[image]

Comment: I've wanted to do this myself. For a single instance, all I have found to do is to cut and paste the cell data, but if you are doing it regularly [this similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1266249/ms-word-tables-how-to-automatically-shift-cells-to-the-right-and-down-after-ins?rq=1) has a solution, but it needs structuring your document differently.